# What is the special status of the value 0 in c++?

Tags: c++, literals, null-pointer

This is purely a philosophical question. I assume that there's no reasonable context in which the result will prove to be useful (given `nullptr`).

According to this - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal, the type of integral literals is either `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`, with possible implementation-specific exceptions if the value of the literal doesn't fit into any of the above.
None of these types are convertible to `void *`, unless the value of the literal is 0.

Different compilers handle this differently.
For example, consider the following conversions:

```
void g(void * p){}

void f(){
    int i = 0;
    void * p;
    // p = i; // Fails. Also for other integral types.

    p = 0; // Works. Also for 00, 0x0 and 0b0. Also when adding `u` and `l` suffixes.
    g(0); // Also works.    
    // g(1); // Fails.  

    // Amazingly, even this seems to work with gcc, icc and msvc, but not with clang:
    void * x = static_cast<int>(0);
    // These works for icc and msvc, but fails with gcc and clang
    p = static_cast<int>(0);
    g(static_cast<int>(0));
}
```

What happens "under the hood" that enables compilers to perform these `int`->`void *` conversions?

---

Edit:
Specifically, the question is what does the standard has to say about this?

Comment: As far as I know this has no consequences whatsoever, but it's always amused me that `0` is an **octal** constant, while `1`..`9` are decimal.

Comment: @Pete Is it though? 0x is not a hexadecimal number. I think that an "octal" zero is `00`.

Comment: Analysis by pun is often misleading. `0b` is not a binary literal and `0x` is not a hexadecimal literal. That's because the grammar rules require that `0b` has to be followed by a binary digit and `0x` has to be followed by a hexadecimal digit. The rules for binary literals and for hexadecimal literals are not the rules for octal literals. `0` is an octal literal whose value is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens "under the hood" that enables compilers to perform these `int`->`void *` conversions?

Magic (or just a dedicated rule, if you prefer). Literal `0` (as well as `0u`, `0l` and other variants) is special. It's only when those exact tokens appear in the source, that the compiler considers the conversion to a pointer as valid. It's not the value of 0, it's the token.

> **[conv.ptr]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.ptr#1) A *null pointer constant* is an **integer literal** with value
>   zero or a prvalue of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`. A null pointer constant
>   can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer
>   value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of
>   object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a
>   *null pointer conversion*.

An "integer literal" has a precise meaning as described in [**[lex.icon]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.icon). It's a specification of tokens that can appear in the source of our program. The quoted paragraph above tells us which of those tokens has a special meaning.

---

I suspect the divergence in behavior you see is due to the C programming language. Depending on how the front-end of the compiler is implemented, it may be a source for this bug. In C, any integer constant expression with the value of 0 is a null pointer constant.

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> [3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an
>   expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If
>   a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

And the same was true in C++ until [CWG Issue 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903) was resolved into the rule we have today in C++.

If some compilers intermingle their C and C++ logic, or haven't caught on to the resolution of the defect report, it would explain your observations.

Answer (score 7):

> The question is, why is this permitted according to the standard

Because there needs to be a way to express null pointer. The designer of the C language chose that 0 would be null. The designer of C++ chose to be compatible with C, and as such 0 is a null pointer constant.

Later in C++11, `nullptr` was introduced as a new keyword. The integral null pointer constants cannot be replaced because that would break backward compatibility, so these different ways to express null co-exist. There is no reason to use 0 as null pointer if you don't need to support pre-C++11 systems.

> and specifically what is permitted

Standard says (latest draft):

> [conv.ptr] A null pointer constant is an integer literal ([lex.icon]) with value zero or a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type ([basic.compound]) and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type.
>   Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion.
>   Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal.
>   The conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and not the sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion ([conv.qual]).
>   A null pointer constant of integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type std​::​nullptr_­t.
>   [ Note: The resulting prvalue is not a null pointer value.
>   — end note
>    ]

---

> What happens "under the hood" that enables compilers to perform these int->void * conversions?

The compiler parses the source. The grammar says that 0 is a literal. The compiler treats is as a literal 0, and as such lets it be converted to any pointer type as per standard.

---

```
// Amazingly, even this seems to work with gcc, icc and msvc, but not with clang:
void * x = static_cast<int>(0);
```

This is ill-formed since C++11. When an ill-formed program compiles, it is typically either because

1. It is a language extension or
2. It is a compiler bug or
3. It is well formed in older version of language, and compiler targets that

In this case, it is probably a language extension.

```
// These works for icc and msvc, but fails with gcc and clang
p = static_cast<int>(0);
g(static_cast<int>(0));
```

These are also ill-formed since C++11. I don't know enough about icc and msvc to tell you whether these cases are intentional. I recommend checking their documentation regarding that.

Comment: Obviously, it's as easy as adding a special case for the value 0. The question is, why is this permitted according to the standard, and specifically what is permitted (because the compilers do not agree).

Comment: @BennyK Because `nullptr` did not exist prior to C++11, and because `NULL` was a macro, so you still needed a value for "null" pointer and 0 was kind of an obvious choice and was already used in C.

Comment: @BennyK You forgot to write the question in your original post.